# How do you find a probability that is out-of-range?

Tags: probability, random-variables

For example, a continuous random variable X has a pdf: f(x) = 2x when a $\le$ x $\le$ b, and f(x) = 0 otherwise. **Now I want to find P(a $\le$ X $\le$ c) , where c is a value outside of the range [a, b], is this possible?** My thought process would be to calculate the probability that's outside the range separately and add that to the probability that is in the range. In this case, since I am using pdf's and continuous rv's, I would integrate from a to b, then add the integration from b to c, or 0 as stated in the pdf. Am I wrong? Does the rule change if you are working with a different type of variable (i.e. discrete rv, Poisson rv, binomial etc)?

Comment: We prefer to see $\leq$.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: @saulspatz Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If $c \gt b,$ the probability $a \lt X \lt c$ is the same as the probability $a \lt X \le b$ because the probability $b \lt X \lt c$ is zero.  The equals does not really matter as the probability for a continuous variable to equal a specific value is zero.